# Multiple ORs and one AND result - Is the AND being applied to each OR?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I have a basic query I am using to do some testing, and I was hoping for some feedback on whether my results are ok. I did cross check my results from about 100 records, and all seems fine, but I am running through about a million records, and I want to make sure my results are accurate.

This is the basic query I am running through a while() loop:

```
    ... OR $row['last_action_txt'] == 'AUTO REC OK' 
    OR $row['action_txt'] == 'MAINT OK'
    OR $row['action_txt'] == 'LASTATUS OK' 
    OR $row['action_txt'] == 'ACCT LEAD OK' 
    AND $row['disp_txt'] == 'ACTIVE') { ...
```

**Does the AND make at least one of the other OR required in order to be true?**

Comment: You should read the …ing manual for questions about such _basics_ – http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
... OR $row['last_action_txt'] == 'AUTO REC OK' 
OR $row['action_txt'] == 'MAINT OK'
OR $row['action_txt'] == 'LASTATUS OK' 
OR ($row['action_txt'] == 'ACCT LEAD OK' AND $row['disp_txt'] == 'ACTIVE')) { ...
```

The `AND` will be applied to the closest `OR` only. This is due to the [precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) of the `AND` operator.

Answer (score 1):

When combining ands and ors, you may need to add some parenthesis to make sure you're getting the right result.  If you want the above to require at least one of the "or"ed values, then you'll want to put parenthesis around all the terms you are ORing.

```
if( ($row['last_action_txt'] == 'AUTO REC OK' 
OR $row['action_txt'] == 'MAINT OK'
OR $row['action_txt'] == 'LASTATUS OK' 
OR $row['action_txt'] == 'ACCT LEAD OK') 
AND $row['disp_txt'] == 'ACTIVE') { ...
```

Where you place the parenthesis will affect how the true and false values determine the outcome.